# CURL - Perform a button click on remote webpage

Tags: php, curl

I started learning PHP around a month or 2 ago. I'm (trying) to make a web application that sends a 'Private Message' on a CMS(content management system), I am not the maker/moderator of this CMS. I've already made a login with CURL but I can't perform the "click".

Button to perform the click on:

```
 <a style="float:right;" class="btn-medium btn-neutral" id="send-btn">Send</a>
```

I have no idea how to perform the click.

Thanks for reading & helping,

Sorry for misspelled words, I'm not English.

Comment: A button click is nothing else than to call the URL with CURL in the attribute `action` of the `form` tag which contains the submit button you want to click.

Comment: So you should use the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`?

Comment: Yes if the `method`of the form is `POST` then you can attach your form data to send as array in the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option.

Comment: Set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true` to get the response content.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER. I've added my whole code, the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` isn't changed, I assume that the `1` stands for `true`. And I already want to thank you for your time.

Comment: Which site you try to login and read a PM? So I can test your code against the scenario. And yes `1` means `true` that's okay.

Comment: I can't even manage to log me in with your code and the URI /newlogin. I get the login page from CURL returned.

Comment: But then you get "has moved to" `/login/default.aspx?name=your_username` so the login also won't work.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER Fixed it by myself, thanks anyway.